# Change colors in legends points (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am novel in R and i am doing a plot with ggplot2 , i would like to change colors for my points in legend (same colours as in the plot)

```
p1 <- ggplot(reliability.plot, aes(x = reorder(Class, -cost_bil),
                                   y = Implementation)) +
geom_point( aes(size=cost_bil), color = col) + 
scale_size(range=c(1,30),
           breaks=c(0.1,1,2,5,10,20,30)) +
rotate_x_text(45)+rotate_y_text(45)+
guides(size=guide_legend(reverse = T)) +
labs(size="US$ billions")+
theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill=NA)+
xlab("Taxonomic Class") + 
ylab("Method reliability") +
theme(text = element_text(size=12)) +
geom_text(aes(label=n),hjust=0.5, vjust=2.5) + 
theme_bw()+
theme_classic()
```

[image: example_plot.png]

Comment: Welcome to SO - I'd suggest reviewing this post about reproducible examples (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and making some edits to get the most from the experience on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Thanks for providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); here is how I would solve your problem:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Load example dataset
example_dataset <- structure(list(ID = 1:6,
                                  Class = c("Amphibia", "Diverse", "Reptilia", "Amphibia", "Diverse", "Reptilia"),
                                  Implementation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                                             .Label = c("Observed", "Potential"),
                                                             class = "factor"),
                                  cost_bil = c(16.78812696789, 0.00755587011, 3.81210675659,
                                               46.26621554247, 0.32702350757, 110.57066587724),
                                  n = c(58190L, 9L, 2482L, 40748L, 3L, 16326L)),
                             row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

# Make "Class" a factor
example_dataset$Class <- factor(example_dataset$Class)

# Create a color palette to map to continuous values
my_pal <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow","firebrick2"))

# Plot the data
ggplot(example_dataset, aes(x = reorder(Class, -cost_bil), y = Implementation)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = cost_bil, color = cost_bil)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("n =", scales::comma(n, accuracy = 1), sep = " ")),
            nudge_y = 0.3) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = my_pal(6)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 30)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = T),
         size = guide_legend(reverse = T)) +
  labs(size = "US$ billions", color = "US$ billions") +
  xlab("Taxonomic Class") +
  ylab("Method reliability") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image: example_2.png]

You can choose discrete colours for this type of plot if you change cost_bil into a factor and use `scale_color_manual()`, but it is not straightforward. If this is really what you want to do (i.e. list the specific color for each dot) I can probably figure out how to do it, but it's not going to be easy and it won't "make sense" (i.e. the change in color won't relate to the change in value)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for your answer, and of course excuse my lack of knowledge on this web (its my first question),

Comment: the output is:                                                                                                                                                structure(list(ID = 1:6, Class = c("Amphibia", "Diverse", "Reptilia", 
"Amphibia", "Diverse", "Reptilia"), Implementation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Observed", "Potential"), class = "factor"), 
    cost_bil = c(16.78812696789, 0.00755587011, 3.81210675659, 
    46.26621554247, 0.32702350757, 110.57066587724), n = c(58190L, 
    9L, 2482L, 40748L, 3L, 16326L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: i am trying with a personal pallete of colors as:      "col=c("darkorange1","yellow2","orange2","orangered","yellow3","firebrick2")"                     but i am not getting the desired result.                                                                                   I have tried to replace "colour" for colour" and some codes by adding layers with "guides".